# How do I register a custom file type association in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, file-type, file-type-associations

I looked at an [existing tutorial](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application) for registering the file type associations in iOS via XCode.
I added my a new entry under `Imported UTIs` for my self-defined custom file type like `.teop` and filled the field for Descriptions/Identifier/Conforms To/Icons. Unfortunately, there seems to be no button for `Additional imported UTI properties`, so I can't follow along the tutorial and I'm I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need that for a known file type like pdf. I just did a test and the additional properties were not necessary for a PDF.

I think they are necessary for custom file types though. If the properties are not available in the Advanced tab, you can set them in the Source tab. The advanced tab is just a GUI for the source tab for easy entry of document/imported uri types, etc. You could actually do it all in the source tab. Same is true for settings in the Application tab: just shortcuts to add key/values to the info.plist file. If you open the info.plist file in a text editor, you will see that it is just an XML file.

That said, in the source tab you can add the additional properties:

[image]

And there is part 2 of the guide you linked that discusses custom file types: https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/ios-tips-and-tricks-associate-a-file-type-with-your-app-part-2

Comment: I'm not asking to open a PDF which is a known file type but I need to open a self-defined custom one.

Comment: You were asking how to set the additional properties. I showed you how to do that. Then I gave a link to another article in the same series you linked that explains setting up a custom file type. Please read my entire answer.